# CSS ~ Hover animation affects the whole page row ISSUE

Tags: html, css, image, animation

So I'm trying to make a simple animation (only changing the opacity) whenever you hover over an image. The issue is that the animation isn't only applied to the image but rather the whole line.
***HTML:***

```
<header>
<div class="logo">
    <img src="images/mofowhite.png" alt="Nik Moder Photography Logo" height="40px">
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.logo {
padding-left: 15px;
padding-top: 5px;
opacity: 60%;
transition: 0.2s;}

.logo:hover {
transition: 0.2s;
opacity: 100%;}
```

***IMAGE:***
*Red=Cursor position* *Blue=Image affected*
[image]

Comment: Have you tried targeting it more directly through: ".logo img" and ".logo img:hover"?

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***ANSWER BY:*** **Djoezz**
Simply target more directly ( using ".logo img" and ".logo img:hover")